# Поиск совпадений регулярным выражением для PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка [A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁЇїІіЄєҐґ\d]{1,}

Вот в этом слове "Кирилл" оно находит два совпадения как "Кир|илл"
если букву р переносить то и граница разделения тоже сместиться.
Например "Киир|лл"
Есть идеи почему так?
При этом КИРИЛЛ нормально находит. Тоже и с мягким знаком:
например Евгень|евич
если в регулярку добавить буквы "р" и "ь" то все ок.
Пример [A-Za-zА-Яа-яёЁЇїІіЄєҐґрь\d]{1,} - находит "Кирилл"

Comment: что за переносы, что за два совпадения, не ясно.

Comment: проверьте где ниь на regex101, если у вас в пхп результат отличен, то напишите его. а так же в каких кодировках файл, и откуда и в какой кодировке берете данные

Comment: Всё как всегда - [`'~REGEX~u'`](https://3v4l.org/8KpOT). Вы забыли **`u`**.

Answer (score -1):

> Всё как всегда - '~REGEX~u'. Вы забыли u

Вот это помогло

Comment: А вообще, зачем такой бред писать, когда придумано `\p{L}` ?